# ng add@angular-material // The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics

Tags: angular, windows, angular-material

VS code, in terminal, angular project root: ng add @angular/material.

Then: The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.

Windows 10; Angular CLI 8.3.23; Node 12.7.0; Angular 8-2.14

Any clues how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried to specify a version? Like this `ng add @angular/material@8.2.3`

Comment: Yes, I got the same message: "The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support."

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. You'll need to first install both @angular/cdk and @angular/material, and only then add the schematics:

1. `npm i @angular/cdk`
2. `npm i @angular/material`
3. `ng add @angular/material`